# Put <h1> below <img> in <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a loading div that I display, and I want to have the text in the `<h1>` below the `<img>` and I can get it aligned in the middle horizontally, but I cant get it aligned below the `<img>` here is my HTML

```
<div id="loading">

  <img id="loading-image" src="http://downgraf.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/01-progress.gif" alt="Loading..." />
  <h1 id="loading_text">Loading...</h1>
</div>
```

And my CSS

```
#loading {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
position: fixed;
display: block; 
z-index: 99;
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);

}


#loading-image {

position: absolute;
margin: auto;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
z-index: 100;
width:10%
}

#loading_text {
color:black;
text-align:center;
z-index: 101;
vertical-align:middle
}
```

And I have included a fiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/myh5f13q/

So how can I get the `<h1>` centered horizontally and below the `<img>`?

Thanks

Comment: The problem occurs because you haven't learned the fundamentals of positioning with CSS. You need to understand, in this case, that absolute positioning removes that element from the normal flow. That is what is causing your problem. This same question is asked constantly on forums and on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove all the positioning and give this way:

```css
#loading {
  display: block;
  z-index: 99;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
#loading-image {
  width: 10%;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
#loading_text {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 101;
  vertical-align: middle
}
```

```html
<div id="loading">
  <img id="loading-image" src="http://downgraf.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/01-progress.gif" alt="Loading..." />
  <h1 id="loading_text">Loading...</h1>
</div>
```

**Preview**

[image]

*Full Screen*

[image]

Comment: I also want them both centered vertically as well

Comment: @iqueqiorio Please tell. I have updated the code for you. `:)`

Comment: great thanks, last thing is there a way to make the div also fill the whole screen. I tried `width:100%;` but that moved everything back to the top

Comment: Yea... Sure. @iqueqiorio.

Comment: @iqueqiorio It is already filling the whole screen. Add `height: 100%` also.

Comment: when I do that it moves to the top as seen here http://jsfiddle.net/myh5f13q/6/, I want the div to be full screen not the img

Comment: @iqueqiorio What did you try doing? Coz it was working fine right?

Comment: I added `with:100%;` and `height:100%` to the div, and then the div is full screen but the img and text move to the top

Answer (score 1):

I would wrap the content in another `<div>` and use CSS transform and position absolute to centre both vertically and horizontally.

Source: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

```css
#loading {
  position: relative;
}
#loading-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="loading">
  <div id="loading-content">
    <img id="loading-image" src="http://downgraf.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/01-progress.gif" alt="Loading..." />
    <h1 id="loading_text">Loading...</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add another container, and [vertically center](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) it within the `#loading` element.

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/gfv08q4z/

```css
#loading {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    z-index: 99;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
#loading-container {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
#loading-image {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width:10%
}
#loading_text {
    color:black;
    text-align:center;
    z-index: 101;
    vertical-align:middle
}
```

```html
<div id="loading">
    <div id="loading-container">
        <img id="loading-image" src="http://downgraf.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/01-progress.gif" alt="Loading..." />
         <h1 id="loading_text">Loading...</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```